# Single page apps keeping client and server in sync

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, ember.js, single-page-application

I am trying to understand how single page apps spa's work.

My understanding of a spa is that you load the data on start-up and you use ajax calls for save etc, and the whole idea is that your models cache data on the client so you have a rich snappy experience in your browser.

I am confused as to how the client stays in sync with the server changes.
E.G. If I have multiple users logged into my spa and they are all making changes, how does my client know that another user has updated a persons details if it is using cached data?

My guess is that something similar needs to happen server side to update the client on a change. Does this exist or am I misunderstanding something?

Any help or pointers to additional info would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511031/A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js) is deprecated (although it doesn't have any warning about it) as it was written based on a previous version of Ember, however it can give you some insights on how to integrate SignalR with your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For server to client communication you can use SignalR.

SignalR allows you to create a hub on the server which you can then tell to update the clients.

It works with a fallback mechanism, it tries to use the following techniques and falls back onto the next one if it's not available in the browser:

- Web Sockets
- server sent events
- forever frame
- long polling

Link for fallbacks: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/introduction/transports-and-fallbacks

Link for signalR: http://signalr.net/

Comment: Thanks Kenneth for you quick response, this seems interesting, this would work for sure, however I wander is there any other options for me to consider that you know of?

Comment: As far as I know, for server to client communication SignalR is the only solution. Of course, you could implement your own solution with polling or web sockets, but that wouldn't be very effective. SignalR is the best way to go, there certainly is nothing that does it *automagically* for your

Comment: If I am to use signalr in my app, what about concurrency i.e. if i have a textbox on my browser which is displaying a person details, and multiple people are attempting to update this persons details. Then this will be problematic because user a is finished updating details, while user b is still writing, therefore user a's changes will update on user b's textbox, which would be very frustrating for user b. There would need to be a locking mechanism on the client for that textbox, and some sort of a rowver on the table being updated server side so concurrency can be checked. Have you seen this

Comment: You need to implement this yourself: when user a puts hic caret in the textbox, you lock the record through SignalR and send that lock to all connected clients. That way you can't have concurrency issues. This video shows a demo on how to do that: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/25

Comment: Thanks for this I will research further.